# if string contains global variable, how to use that global variable?

Tags: python, string, list, global-variables, global

I couldn't find an answer for this, so can you give a beginner pythonist some help. I have a string and if it is in globals, then I want to use that variable to manipulate it. I get an error that I'm using string to append, when my global variable is a list.

```
color = []
keyword = "color"
if keyword in globals():
    keyword.append("testing")
```

Comment: `globals()[keyword]` gives you the object.

Comment: You don't concat strings like that! Will give you an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary, which you can use like any other dictionary

```
globals()[keyword] = <my_new_value>
```

Comment: Thank you :). And what if I wanted to append a value from the list? globals()[keyword].append("testing") @blue_note

Comment: @user3152311: If you *know* that the `globals()[keyword]` is already a list, then `globals()[keyword].append("testing")` should work.